# Where does this formula for area of a triangle come from?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I'm not good at entering formulas into text editors so I'm going to paste a few lines of code here:

Given an arbitrary triangle formed by points 1, 2 and 3, where side-lengths a, b and e are as follows:

a = dist (1,3)
b = dist (3,2)
e = dist (1,2)

d = (b*b - a*a + e*e) / (2*e)

c = e - d

hh = a * a - c * c

h = sqr(hh)

area = .5 * (c*h + h*d)

This does not seem to be "Heron's Formula" - so does it have a name?

Comment: Consider looking at this to enter the formulas : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you can tell us what $c, d$ and $h$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your post is consistent with the diagram below, in which $c + d = e$, or $c = e - d$, hence
$$
c^{2} = (e - d)^{2} = e^{2} - 2de + d^{2}
\tag{1}
$$
and, by the Pythagorean theorem,
$$
h^{2} = a^{2} - c^{2},
\tag{2}
$$
so
\begin{align*}
  d^{2} &= b^{2} - h^{2} && \text{Pythagorean theorem} \\
  &= b^{2} - (a^{2} - c^{2}) && \text{equation (2)} \\
  &= b^{2} - a^{2} + c^{2} && \\
  &= b^{2} - a^{2} + e^{2} - 2de + d^{2} && \text{equation (1).}
\end{align*}
Canceling the $d^{2}$s and solving for $d$ gives
$$
d = \frac{b^{2} - a^{2} + e^{2}}{2e}
$$
as you say, and the area of the triangle is
$$
\tfrac{1}{2}eh = \tfrac{1}{2}(c + d)h = \tfrac{1}{2}(ch + dh).
$$
This formula does not have a standard name other than "the area of a triangle of height $h$ and base $e$".

[image: The area of a triangle by dividing into two right triangles]